# Pagedown Image upload with Rails and Paperclip

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, pagedown

Still new to Rails and Javascript and this problem has me stumped.

I'm trying to get a image upload feature added to a Pagedown editor in my rails app.  I am using Paperclip for file uploads.

I tried following this tutorial http://multiplethreads.wordpress.com/2013/04/09/image-upload-to-the-pagedown-markdown-editor-via-ajax-in-rails/ but I am missing something.  I can get the modal to show correctly, and the image upload form displays correctly.  The images do not get uploaded and the URL of the file obviously does not display in the editor.

Rails is not displaying any errors, but it is just not working.

**Image callback**

```
  editor.hooks.set "insertImageDialog", (callback) ->
  setTimeout (->
    $("#fileModal").modal('show')
    $("#insert_image_post").click (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
      if $(".upload-photo").length > 0
        images = $(".upload-photo").each ->
          images = "" + ($(this).filter("[src]").attr("src"))
          return

        callback images
        $("#upload_photo").fileupload()
      else
        image = $("#img-url").val()
        callback image
      $("#fileModal").modal "hide"
      return

    return
  ), 0
  true
```

**Modal**

```
        <!-- Modal -->
<%= f.simple_fields_for :asset do |asset| %>
<div id="fileModal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="fileModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
   <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
     <h3 id="fileModalLabel">Upload Images</h3>
     </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="tabbable tabs-left"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Upload</a></li>
           <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Enter URL</a></li>
       </ul>
     <div class="tab-content">
       <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
         <%= asset.file_field :asset %>
         <div class="preview" id="preview" >
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
       <div class="form-group">
         <p><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex: http://yoursite.com/image.jpg" id="img-url" /></p>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div> <!-- End of Modal-Body -->
 <div class="modal-footer">
   <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
   <button class="btn" id="insert_image_post">Insert Image</button>
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
<% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey, did you get this sorted out?